How to make a usb for booting a fresh new computer, which contains a new nvme 2.0 ssd?
After installing centos7.9 failed, I change all the efforts to the ubuntu server which turns out to be also a frustrating result:
Issue: the bios of the computer does not recognize the usb which containing a ubuntu 22.04 live server.
Material List:

Image ISO: Ubuntu 22.04 live server
Burning Tool: rufus@4.6
Booting USB: FAT32 format, Containing Ubuntu 22.04 live server
NVME 2.0 SSD: Windows NTFS format(which I check and formats today)


you might have more success by installing on a Ventoy USB. Simply ensure that your download is from a valid resource, verify the .iso file and copy it to the Ventoy stick.

You cannot install Ubuntu to NTFS, a Microsoft Windows format. If UEFI system which all new systems are, you need gpt partitioning, not old MBR(msdos) which many tools still default to. And then at minimum ESP - efi system partition as FAT32  & / (root) as ext4 or other Linux format. Many with servers use LVM or logical volumes inside one partition. If system is new, you may need 24.04.1 to have latest kernel & drivers to support newer hardware.

ok, i would give it try for ventoy, many thanks to graham

@oldfred ok, thanks, i would take your advice of installing the ubuntu live server 24.04 version, and formats the ssd into ext4, and formats the usb into fat32 !

Be aware if you're reformatting the ISO when writing (ie. using options within rufus to do so, and not just cloning the ISO to your install media unchanged) you need to use options that are suitable for your specific hardware.  A cloned ISO will boot & install on legacy, uEFI & Secure-Boot uEFI hardware, where a reformatted (via options at write) ISO will be specific to the options you selected  (you'll risk not being able to boot it, or problems writing boot loader thus first boot can fail etc).  Just follow official documented ISO writing procedures for best results.

This question is similar to: Why Doesn't a Bootable USB Boot. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

ext4 issue: i bought a nvme ssd box for formating the ssd today, and i would follow the instructions of ubuntu installing steps of the web site, the situations i met installing the ubuntu system would be described more tommorrow,  many thinks to you kind hearted people ! And I would not be defeated by the installing problem

ok, i would edit the situation i met later when i receive the nvme box, and would try all the possible steps provided @karel

OK, if you have any questions just comment to me at @karel and I will try to answer them.

Finally, I resolve the installing issues before i made decision to send back to the online seller for helping installing ubuntu server.
Here are some crucial points what I figour out:

No need to give partion for the SSD

ubuntu server would take care of that

Send the ldlinux.sys file to the bootable usb after UltraISO burned ubuntu server files

It is the most important step which I think in the installing progress, especially when all the files of ubuntu server iso are flushed by the ultrasio .

click the easy start button
writing into new drive boot sector
syslinux

Click the easy start button

Making sure the bootable usb type is: MBR - FAT32

I wonder at first if I am wrong about setting the usb to be a wrong class as MBR, so change it into GPT.
Just leave it to be MBR as default, no need to pay extra attention about this.

Thanks to the kind hearted people: @karel @oldfred @graham
